# X server error when PyQt5 is used to generate pdf from html

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying PyQt5 for converting a html to a pdf (have previously used pdfkit but notice now that not all plots in the html are included in the pdf) but get X server error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import argparse
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys


def mkParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="html to pdf")
    parser.add_argument("--html", type=str, required=True, help="report.html")
    parser.add_argument("--out", type=str, required=True, help="name of pdf file")

    return parser.parse_args()



def html_to_pdf(doc, pdf):

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    page = QWebEnginePage()

    def handle_print_finished(filename, status):
        print("finished", filename, status)

    def handle_load_finished(status):
        if status:
            page.printToPdf(pdf, layout=QPageLayout(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4), QPageLayout.Portrait))
        else:
            print("failed")

    page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(handle_print_finished)
    page.loadFinished.connect(handle_load_finished)
    page.setHtml(doc)

    QApplication.exit()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    return pdf


def main():
    args = mkParser()
    html_to_pdf(args.html, args.out)

main()
```

Running this in the terminal in an X2Go session (in Pycharms venv)
renders:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: X server does not support XInput 2
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!
[345570:345629:0128/094029.366269:ERROR:gl_surface_glx_qt.cpp(141)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[345570:345629:0128/094029.366303:ERROR:gl_ozone_glx_qt.cpp(57)] GLSurfaceGLXQt::InitializeOneOff failed.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running it using ssh -X login to the server (also in Pycharms venv) renders:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please advise

Comment: Is the `DISPLAY` env variable properly set when using ssh -X? And is X forwarding enabled/allowed on both machines?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment by @musicamante and some additional searching it's now solved by ssh -X using MobaXterm  while disabling the "RANDR" MobaXTerm X11 extension

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).